# Suppressing text and mail merge fields in Word based on another mail merge field

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

Our Student Information System (SIS) uses Word's mail merge functionality to create custom documents.  I'm attempting to recreate a state-supplied form, and need some help.

In the document I've got six "sources": for each one there's a checkbox, a static text description, and a description field.  I want to display the six as separate rows, but if the checkbox for that row is unchecked I don't want that row to display at all; I also don't want the checkbox to actually display here (it'll be displayed in a different place).  The effect I'm looking for is a table where each row's visibility is controlled by the checkbox, and empty rows collapse.

When I create the document, the SIS creates a starter document with all of the fields referenced.  After a little massaging, here's what I have:

```
{ MERGEFIELD TableStart:REV_DATA_ROOT/StudentDocument \*MERGEFORMAT}
    { MERGEFIELD @CogS1??TYPE=CHECKBOX} Source 1 { MERGEFIELD @CogS1Desc}
    { MERGEFIELD @CogS2??TYPE=CHECKBOX} Source 2 { MERGEFIELD @CogS2Desc}
    { MERGEFIELD @CogS3??TYPE=CHECKBOX} Source 3 { MERGEFIELD @CogS3Desc}
    { MERGEFIELD @CogS4??TYPE=CHECKBOX} Source 4 { MERGEFIELD @CogS4Desc}
    { MERGEFIELD @CogS5??TYPE=CHECKBOX} Source 5 { MERGEFIELD @CogS5Desc}
    { MERGEFIELD @CogS6??TYPE=CHECKBOX} Source 6 { MERGEFIELD @CogS6Desc}
{ MERGEFIELD TableEnd:REV_DATA_ROOT/StudentDocument \*MERGEFORMAT}
```

So if only the checkboxes for Source 1 and Source 5 were checked, only those two lines would display:

```
 Source 1   Et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis.
 Source 5   Ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna.
```

(if the description wraps to the next line I'll play with the tabs and the hanging indent to mimic an actual table)

What I specifically want to avoid is having a blank line where unchecked checkboxes are.  Is this possible?

Edit: When I print @CogS1, etc., by itself without setting the type to checkbox, it prints either True or False, so it should be possible to use this in an `IF` statement, but I'm not getting it to work.  Also, in the original code above I had typed a single question mark just before "TYPE=CHECKBOX"; it's actually two question marks, and the code has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: Not really possible to answer without access to the actual data, more specifically, the data underlying `{MERGEFIELD @CogS1?TYPE=CHECKBOX}`. If you have something in that datasource that returns something that can be tested using **IF**, it should be possible. Can you provide something like that? (Please use the [edit] link to add the information directly to the question.)

Comment: I should have included that information, and have updated the question.  Thank you.

Comment: @Jim Stephenson: A problem is that the syntax you have for your { MERGEFIELD } fields is not "normal" MERGEFIELD syntax. When I first read your question, I wondered whether your SIS system was using code to replace, e.e., "CogS1?TYPE=CHECKBOX" by a more specific column name prior to a merge. If so, not obvious to readers of this question (and perhaps not to you!).   In addition, as a general rule, if the value of a MERGEFIELD field called CogS1 is True, i.e. the text value True, you need a test that matches the MERGEFIELD value to the text value "True".

Comment: As mentioned by Yokki in comments, the SIS system you're using appears to be doing something behind the scenes with the data  source and what it's delivering. It's not even certain that a true mail merge is being executed, rather than code doing something with the merge fields in the document. If this turns out to *not* be a true mail merge then you'll need to contact your system administration about your problem - it's not something we can solve...

Comment: With the above caveat, please also edit in the IF field you attempted. If we see a problem with that, we can make a suggestion. If it looks correct, then my comment above applies.

Comment: After more research, including contacting the vendor, it turns out you are both correct about the SIS adding its own flavor to Word's mail merge: in the merge field `(MERGEFIELD @CogS1??TYPE=CHECKBOX}` the "`??TYPE=CHECKBOX`" portion makes the field return a checked box if `@CogS1` is `true`, or an unchecked box if it's any other value.  In hindsight I should have removed that portion of the merge field from the example fields as it ended up distracting from the solution.   That said, I figured out how to do what I needed (answer is below).

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem I needed to use IF merge fields with a carriage return embedded in the "True" results; I also needed to have no carriage returns between the six IF merge fields.  Based on the example I gave originally, here's what I ended up doing:

```
{IF {MERGEFIELD @CogS1} = "true" "Source 1: {MERGEFIELD @CogS1Desc}
"}{IF {MERGEFIELD @CogS2} = "true" "Source 2: {MERGEFIELD @CogS2Desc}
" ""}{IF {MERGEFIELD @CogS3} = "true" "Source 3: {MERGEFIELD @CogS3Desc}
" ""}{IF {MERGEFIELD @CogS4} = "true" "Source 4: {MERGEFIELD @CogS4Desc}
" ""}{IF {MERGEFIELD @CogS5} = "true" "Source 5: {MERGEFIELD @CogS5Desc}
" ""}{IF {MERGEFIELD @CogS6} = "true" "Source 6: {MERGEFIELD @CogS6Desc}
" ""}
```